# Can't download multiple images from array using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const Fs = require('fs')  
const Path = require('path')  
const Axios = require('axios')
var dir = './tmp';


async function downloadImage () {  
if (!Fs.existsSync(dir)){
 Fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}
 var arr = ['https://reaperscans.com/wp-content/uploads/WP-manga/data/manga_6295b8da2aa90/5461fc34b58cd174c806625056c6e0dc/01-copy.jpg','https://reaperscans.com/wp-content/uploads/WP-manga/data/manga_6295b8da2aa90/5461fc34b58cd174c806625056c6e0dc/02-copy.jpg','https://reaperscans.com/wp-content/uploads/WP-manga/data/manga_6295b8da2aa90/5461fc34b58cd174c806625056c6e0dc/03-copy.jpg']
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
var  url = arr[i]
  
 var name = i  + '.jpg'
 
  var path = Path.resolve(__dirname,dir, name)
  var writer = Fs.createWriteStream(path)

  var response = await Axios({
    url,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'stream'
  })

  response.data.pipe(writer)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    writer.on('finish', resolve)
    writer.on('error', reject)
  })
  
}
}
downloadImage()
```

This is the above code I am using to download images when I tried downloading multiple images whose links are in array it only downloads the image of first array i.e. arr[0] and can't figure out what's the problem it doesn't give any error to and i can individually download single images but not bulky.[random manga generator](https://mangareadhere.xyz/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I played around with this code snippet and I was able to fix by removing the promise callback at the bottom of your for loop. You were right, it would only complete one GET request, and then terminate. It now runs through all three, and saves it in your ./tmp directory.const

```
Fs = require("fs");
const Path = require("path");
const Axios = require("axios");
var dir = "./tmp";

async function downloadImage() {
  if (!Fs.existsSync(dir)) {
    Fs.mkdirSync(dir);
  }
  var arr = [
    "https://reaperscans.com/wp-content/uploads/WP-manga/data/manga_6295b8da2aa90/5461fc34b58cd174c806625056c6e0dc/01-copy.jpg",
    "https://reaperscans.com/wp-content/uploads/WP-manga/data/manga_6295b8da2aa90/5461fc34b58cd174c806625056c6e0dc/02-copy.jpg",
    "https://reaperscans.com/wp-content/uploads/WP-manga/data/manga_6295b8da2aa90/5461fc34b58cd174c806625056c6e0dc/03-copy.jpg"
  ];


  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var url = arr[i];
    // for debugging
    console.log(arr[i])
    var name = i + ".jpg";
    var path = Path.resolve(__dirname, dir, name);
    var writer = Fs.createWriteStream(path);

    var response = await Axios({
      url,
      method: "GET",
      responseType: "stream"
    });
    // for debugging
    console.log(response)
  }
}
downloadImage();
```

Comment: Don't know why promise callback would interfere it anyway thanks

Comment: Yes, all a bit odd. But, seemed to fix it!